# Scaling resolutions on MBP Late 2013 with 4K monitor

Tags: display, resolution

I'm connecting my Late 2013 MBP with Iris Pro graphics to a Seiki 39" 4K monitor. *Seemingly at random*, I get two different types of Settings->Displays screens:

[image: Screen 1]

[image: Screen 2]

Importantly, Screen 2 lets me choose my favorite resolution - a scaled display with effective 2560x1440 pixels. Screen 1 only lets me choose 1920x1080 at HiDPI, which makes screen elements too large. Alt-clicking 'Scaled' on Screen 1 **doesn't** help. I do get more choices, but not 2560x1440 HiDPI.

How do I always force Screen 2?